# What is the best way to return List of a class type at runtime using interface in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a requirement to return Screen class with two property one is GridConfiguration and second is GridData, GridConfiguration will be an always same type but GridData type will be changing on the basis of screenName at runtime. I have written some code and also able to achieve my goal.

Can anyone let me know what is the best way to achieve the same as per oops concept, I m bit confuse regarding the concepts because in all property class I am implementing the method of the interface.

How Can I achieve the same using factory pattern?.

```
class Programs {
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        string screenName = "Departure"; 
        IGridType gridType = GetGridType(screenName); 
        Screen s = new Screen(); 
        s.GridConfiguration = GetGridConfiguration(); 
        s.GridData = GetGridData(gridType); 
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static List<IGridType> GetGridData(IGridType gridType)
    { 
         List<IGridType> grid = new List<IGridType>(); 
         grid.AddRange(gridType.GetGridData()); 
         return grid; 
    }

    private static IGridType GetGridType(string screenData) 
    { 
        switch (screenData) 
        {
            case "Arrival": return new ArrivalDTO(); 
            case "Departure": return new DepartureDTO(); 
            default: return null; 
        } 
    }

    private static List<GridConfiguration> GetGridConfiguration() 
    { 
        List<GridConfiguration> gridConfiguration = new List<GridConfiguration>(); 
        return gridConfiguration; 
    } 
} 

public interface IGridType 
{ 
    IEnumerable<IGridType> GetGridData(); 
}

public class ArrivalDTO : IGridType 
{ 
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public string FlightNumber { get; set; } 
    public DateTime ArrivalTime { get; set; } 
    public DateTime SchduledTime { get; set; } 
    public IEnumerable<IGridType> GetGridData() 
    { 
        ArrivalService.ArrivalService a = new ArrivalService.ArrivalService(); 
        return a.GetArrivalData(); 
    } 
} 

public class DepartureDTO: IGridType 
{ 
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public string FlightNumber { get; set; } 
    public DateTime DepartureTime { get; set; } 
    public DateTime SchduledTime { get; set; } 
    public IEnumerable<IGridType> GetGridData() 
    { 
        DepartureService.DepartureService a = new DepartureService.DepartureService(); 
        return a.GetDepartureData(); 
    } 
} 

public class GridConfiguration 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string ColumnName { get; set; } 
    public int Index { get; set; } 
    public int FilterText { get; set; } 
} 

public class DepartureService 
{ 
    public List<DepartureDTO> GetDepartureData() 
    {
        List<DepartureDTO> list = new List<DepartureDTO>(); 
        list.Add(new DepartureDTO { ID = 1, DepartureTime = DateTime.Now, FlightNumber = "test" });
        list.Add(new DepartureDTO { ID = 2, DepartureTime = DateTime.Now, FlightNumber = "test2" }); 
        return list;
    }
} 

class ArrivalService 
{ 
    public List<ArrivalDTO> GetArrivalData() 
    { 
        List<ArrivalDTO> list = new List<ArrivalDTO>(); 
        list.Add(new ArrivalDTO { ID = 1, ArrivalTime = DateTime.Now, FlightNumber = "test" }); 
        list.Add(new ArrivalDTO { ID = 2, ArrivalTime = DateTime.Now, FlightNumber = "test2" }); 
        return list; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your code is hard to read, you should try and format it in vertical rather than horizontal style.

Comment: Please explain what to “change on the basis of screenName at runtime” means.

Comment: i mean screenName is just a flag from user like here string screenName = "Departure"; so the GridData will be DepartureDto List type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Vidmantas on the Factory Pattern snip, but I've got a few more suggestions on the code.  Your code works fine, but it doesn't do a good job on "separation of concerns"  Every method and type you've outlined needs inherent knowledge of "how to configure" your types..  This is a fragile way to write code.

In your snippet:

```
    string screenName = "Departure";
    IGridType gridType = GetGridType(screenName);

    Screen s = new Screen();
    s.GridConfiguration = GetGridConfiguration();
    s.GridData = GetGridData(gridType);
```

The first part here is OK.  But it's now a good idea, to have to "configure the screen type" manually after creating it.  You didn't include code for the "screen type" so I inferred a simple type.  It would be better to configure the screen type internally.  Your method "GetGridType(screenName)" Should be a call to a factory method to create AND configure the type.

Something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Programs
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Screen screenDepartures = ScreenFactory.CreateScreen("Departure");
        Screen screenArrivals = ScreenFactory.CreateScreen("Arrival");

        //Whatever you are doing with the screens here..


        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static class ScreenFactory
    {
        public static Screen CreateScreen(string screenData)
        {
            Screen screen = new Screen {GridConfiguration = GetGridConfiguration()};

            switch (screenData)
            {
                case "Arrival":
                {
                    screen.GridData = new ArrivalDTO().GridData();
                    break;
                }
                case "Departure":
                {
                    screen.GridData = new DepartureDTO().GridData();
                    break;
                }
                default: return null;
            }

            return screen;
        }

        private static List<GridConfiguration> GetGridConfiguration()
        {
            List<GridConfiguration> gridConfiguration = new List<GridConfiguration>();
            return gridConfiguration;
        }
    }
}

internal class Screen
{
    public IEnumerable<GridConfiguration> GridConfiguration { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IGridType> GridData { get; set; }

}

public interface IGridType
{
    IEnumerable<IGridType> GridData();
}


public abstract class BaseDTO : IGridType
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FlightNumber { get; set; }

    public DateTime SchduledTime { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<IGridType> GridData()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class ArrivalDTO : BaseDTO
{
    public DateTime ArrivalTime { get; set; }
    public override IEnumerable<IGridType> GridData()
    {
        return new ArrivalService().GetArrivalData();
    }
}

public class DepartureDTO : BaseDTO
{   public DateTime DepartureTime { get; set; }
    public override IEnumerable<IGridType> GridData()
    {
        return new DepartureService().GetDepartureData();
    }
}

public class GridConfiguration
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ColumnName { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public int FilterText { get; set; }
}

public class DepartureService
{
    public IEnumerable<DepartureDTO> GetDepartureData()
    {
        List<DepartureDTO> list = new List<DepartureDTO>();
        list.Add(new DepartureDTO { ID = 1, DepartureTime = DateTime.Now, FlightNumber = "test" });
        list.Add(new DepartureDTO { ID = 2, DepartureTime = DateTime.Now, FlightNumber = "test2" });
        return list;
    }
}

class ArrivalService
{
    public IEnumerable<ArrivalDTO> GetArrivalData()
    {
        List<ArrivalDTO> list = new List<ArrivalDTO>();
        list.Add(new ArrivalDTO { ID = 1, ArrivalTime = DateTime.Now, FlightNumber = "test" });
        list.Add(new ArrivalDTO { ID = 2, ArrivalTime = DateTime.Now, FlightNumber = "test2" });
        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine in this context I suppose, if you want this to resemble the factory pattern for creating `IGridTypes` then just extract your `private static IGridType GetGridType(string screenData)` method into a separate static factory class with this single method and call it `public static IGridType CreateGridType(...)`

```
    public static class GridTypeFactory
    {
        public static IGridType CreateGridType(string screenData)
        {
            switch (screenData)
            {
                case "Arrival": return new ArrivalDTO();
                case "Departure": return new DepartureDTO();
                default: return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

And the usage will be like this.

```
        var gridType = GridTypeFactory.CreateGridType("Arrival");
```

This is a fairly common approach to map strings to types (especially when there are no conventions) by burying them in these factory methods somewhere in your codebase.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a service factory. For this to work the srvices must implement the interface

```
public interface IDtoService
{
    IEnumerable<IGridType> GetData();
}
```

The service factory:

```
public static ServiceFactory
{
    public static IDtoService GetService(string dataType)
    {
        switch (dataType)
        {
            case "Arrival":
                return new ArrivalService();
            case "Departure":
                return new DepartureDTO();
            default:
                throw new NonImplementedException("ServiceFactory.GetService cannot create service for " +  dataType);
        }
    }
}
```

Load the grid with:

```
private static void AddGridData(string dataType)
{
    var service = ServiceFactory.GetService(dataType);
    var data = service.GetData().ToList();
    grid.AddRange(data);
}
```

The grid types would not have a `GetGridData` method anymore. If the DTO objects have no common base class (besides `object`) or interface, the interface `IGridType` is not required and the services can return non-generic `IEnumerable`s.

```
public interface IDtoService
{
    IEnumerable GetData();
}
```